# Retornar resultados em inputs diferentes

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, aplicação-web

Galera, eis o meu código. Minha consulta está retornando os resultados que quero, porém, está retornando somente em um input. Como faço para retornar o name_id num input e o location em outro?

```
<?php   
    $nome = $_POST['name'];

    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        require '../db/conexao.php';
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM names where name = '" . $nome . "'";
        $resultado = $conexao->query($consulta);

         while ($row = $resultado-> fetch()){
         echo $row['location'];
         echo $row['name_id'];  }
    }
        //echo (mysql_num_rows($resultado) !== 0) ? mysql_result($resultado,0,'location') : 'Not found';

?>
```

```js
$('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
 var name= $('input#name').val();
 if ($.trim(name) != ''){
  $.post('ajax/name.php',{name: name}, function(data){
   $('#name-data').val(data);   
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
 Name: <input type="text" id="name">
 <input type="button" id="name-submit" value="Grabs"> 
 <input type="text" id="name-data">
 <input type="text" id="name-datado">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz echo de um JSON com `json_encode`, assim recebes um objeto json no JavaScript. Vais ter mais que um resultado? senão também ter `LIMIT 1` na query e fazer diretamente `echo` do `fetch` sem o `while`.

Mas testa assim:

PHP:

$nome = $_POST['name'];

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    require '../db/conexao.php';
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM names where name = '" . $nome . "'";
    $resultado = $conexao->query($consulta);

     while ($row = $resultado-> fetch()){
         echo json_encode($row);
     }
}
```

e no jQuery:

```js
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
  var name = $('input#name').val();
  if ($.trim(name) != '') {
    $.post('ajax/name.php', {
      name: name
    }, function(data) {
      $('#name-data').val(data.location);
      $('#name-datado').val(data.name_id);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Segui seu exemplo, porém, agora os resultados pararam de vir. =/

Comment: @RodrigoCaio algum erro na consola?

Comment: Não. Apenas os resultados pararam de ir para o input

Comment: @RodrigoCaio na consola podes ver a barra/pasta `network`. Algum erro lá? podes ver o `.post` a sair e o retorno?

Comment: Os dados não estão saindo eu acho

Comment: Algum erro no PHP? qual é a versão de PHP que tens?

Comment: Minha Versão 5.5.38

Comment: @RodrigoCaio vais ter mais que 1 resultado nessa pesquiza?